# How to write a auto adjusting html grid to given number of images( something like technique used in getloupe)

Tags: html

can someone help me to create a Html grid which will automatically adjust it's inner div( images size) to keep the shape steady ( square ) a similar technique used in www.getloupe.com .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you mention the `height` and `width`of the element in `style` attribute. You can even use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

If you want to calculate it using js, first give the element an `id` and then use this code:-

```
<script>
var variablename = document.getElementById("Elementid");
variablename.style.height = document.body.offsetWidth * (fraction/decimal) + "px";
variablename.style.width = document.body.offsetWidth * (fraction/decimal) + "px";
</script>
```